# Disparity map to Point Cloud is off

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, point-clouds, open3d

I am trying to do 3D face reconstruction from two images using Python and OpecCV. I managed to perform camera calibration using intructions from here [link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html), and then applying `cv2.stereoCalibrate()` and `cv2.stereoRectify()`. Afterwards, the `cv2.StereoSGBM` was used to compute the disparity map, and finally `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D` for generating the point cloud. The latter was displayed using `open3d` library. However, the result of `StereoSGBM.compute()` is very noisy, and the resulting point cloud looks nothing like it should.

Things I tried:

- normalizing the disparity map: The algorithm outputs a 2D array with values between -16 and 240, so I adjusted it to be between 0 and 255, and 0.0 and 1.0 respectively. The first option went better
- dividing the values by 16 (as I've seen in the C++ implementation)
- adjusting the paramaters of the StereoSGBM. I even built a GUI to tune the parameters, however the results were still not satisfactory
- using StereoBM, however there was not too much difference
- using different test images
- using graysale images
- normalizing them in range 0.0 -> 1.0
- cropping the undistorted images
- reimplementing `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D`, with the same results
- manually removing the background in the disparity map
- working with uint8 and float32. The reprojection worked way better using the floats

Resulting images:

- initial:
  [image: Left Image] [image: Right Image]
- after calibration:
  [image: Undistorted Left] [image: Undistorted Right]
- disparity map (params on the right):
  [image: Disparity] [image: Params]
- point cloud (looks human looking from a very specific angle):
  [image: Point Cloud]

What can I do to get usable results? I don't even know how the images should look like. Does my calibration seem off? I have a feeling the images are really bad (as the perspective distortion is pretty big), but I have to work with these unfortunately

Some code stubs:

```
_, self.camera_matrix, self.distortion, _, _ = \
            cv2.calibrateCamera(self.object_points, self.image_points, self.image_size, None, None)

error, _, _, _, _, self.rotation, self.translation, _, _ = \
            cv2.stereoCalibrate(self.camera_left.object_points,
                                self.camera_left.image_points,
                                self.camera_right.image_points,
                                self.camera_left.camera_matrix,
                                self.camera_left.distortion,
                                self.camera_right.camera_matrix,
                                self.camera_right.distortion,
                                self.camera_left.image_size,
                                flags=cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)

self.rotation_left, self.rotation_right, self.perspective_left, self.perspective_right, self.Q, self.roi_left, self.roi_right = \
            cv2.stereoRectify(self.camera_left.camera_matrix,
                              self.camera_left.distortion,
                              self.camera_right.camera_matrix,
                              self.camera_right.distortion,
                              self.camera_left.image_size,
                              self.rotation,
                              self.translation,
                              flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY)

self.rotation_left, self.rotation_right, self.perspective_left, self.perspective_right, self.Q, self.roi_left, self.roi_right = \
            cv2.stereoRectify(self.camera_left.camera_matrix,
                              self.camera_left.distortion,
                              self.camera_right.camera_matrix,
                              self.camera_right.distortion,
                              self.camera_left.image_size,
                              self.rotation,
                              self.translation,
                              flags=cv2.CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY)

self.block_matching = cv2.StereoSGBM().create() # params not mentioned here, but they are set
disparity = self.block_matching.compute(undistorted_left, undistorted_right)
disparity = cv2.convertScaleAbs(disparity, beta=16)

point_cloud = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity_image, Q)
point_cloud = point_cloud.reshape(-1, point_cloud.shape[-1])
point_cloud = point_cloud[~np.isinf(point_cloud).any(axis=1)]

pcl = open3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcl.points = open3d.utility.Vector3dVector(point_cloud)
open3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcl])
```